# htaccess ignore if not present

Tags: php, regex, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

Im trying to use htaccess to make my pages a little easier to read.

I am turning this URL:

```
index.php?page=list&console=$1&letter=$2&sort=$3&dorder=$4&page_num=$5 [NC]
```

Into:

```
RewriteRule ^roms/([^/\.]+)/([^/\.]+)/([^/\.]+)/([^/\.]+)/([0-9]+)/?$
```

This is the full code:

```
RewriteRule ^roms/([^/\.]+)/([^/\.]+)/([^/\.]+)/([^/\.]+)/([0-9]+)/?$ /index.php?page=list&console=$1&letter=$2&sort=$3&dorder=$4&page_num=$5 [NC]
```

How can i make it so if one of the variables isnt present for example if the sort=$3 dosent containt anything how can i stop it going to a 404.

Because if i use the long URL and put:

```
/index.php?page=list&console=ABCD&letter=T&sort=&dorder=asc&page_num=5
```

That works fine, Even though sort has nothing in it. but with the rewrite rule it just takes to 404 error.

Thanks

Comment: What happens if you rewrite [NC] to [L]?

Comment: You lack fundamental understanding of the directives you use. I suggest you learn about that feature a bit more so that you can use it according to your needs (it is highly likely this will turn well for your needs) - http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_rewrite.html -- http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/rewrite/

Comment: Changing NC to L still doesn't do anything, I will have a look through the links you set me.

Comment: Can all the query parameters be optional?

Comment: Yes they can be, and in the long url when theyre not there it still works fine, But with the rewrite rule if anything if left out i just get a 404 error.

Comment: The thing that you say you are turning the long url into is NOT what you are turning it into. Please give us an example of one of the short urls that work and one that doesn't.

Comment: This work
    roms/nds/all/r_number/asc/1/

this dosen't
    roms/nds/all//asc/1/

Comment: by leaving out the "r_number" part it gives a 404 Error. Some of the parameters are optional so if it isn't there i still want the page to load

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For making each part in URL optional following is the code that will work for you:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks -MultiViews
# Turn mod_rewrite on
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^$ [NC]
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]{3,}\s/+roms/([^/\.]*)(?:/([^/\.]*)(?:/([^/\.]*)(?:/([^/\.]*)(?:/([^/]*))?)?)?)?/?[\s?] [NC]
RewriteRule ^ /index.php?page=list&console=%1&letter=%2&sort=%3&dorder=%4&page_num=%5 [L,QSA]
```

**It is important to use `THE_REQUEST` variable here otherwise multiple `//` will be striped to single `/`**

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is the regular expression. The + in each group says "match one or more times". If you have nothing in there then it cannot match at all. Hence the 404. Try changing all the +s to *s.

Comment: Thank you, that works great. Guess i didn't explain it very well.

Comment: However your regular expression still isn't doing what you are expecting it to methinks.

Comment: @Exoon: Even with `*` its not going to work you are expecting i.e. making each part optional.

Comment: Yeah it still isn't 100% right actually for example, This WORKS: index.php?page=list&console=nds&letter=all&sort=&dorder=desc&page_num=1 Even though $sort contains no data,   However, roms/nds/all//asc/5/ DOESN'T work, It doesn't give a 404 anymore but it says Empty query. Any ideas how i can fix that?